# InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Unknown name value [] for enum class

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have an enum in my Model:

```
public class RealTimeUpdateLog {
    
    public enum PROG_STATUS {INPROGRESS, SUCCESS, FAILURE};

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private PROG_STATUS progStatus;
    ...
    public PROG_STATUS getProgStatus() {
        return progStatus;
    }

    public void setProgStatus(PROG_STATUS progStatus) {
        this.progStatus = progStatus;
    }
}
```

I am trying to read from db:

```
@Query("select rtl from RealTimeUpdateLog rtl, RealTimeUpdateLog prtl where rtl.orderId=prtl.orderId and" +
            " prtl.customerId=?1 and prtl.seq+1=?2 and prtl.syncCompleted=true and (rtl.progStatus <>?4 or rtl.progStatus is null) and rtl.customerId=?1 and rtl.seq=?2 and rtl.syncCompleted=false and rtl.retryCount>=0 and rtl.retryCount<=?3")
    List<RealTimeUpdateLog> findAllIfPreviousSyncedByOrder(Long customerId, int seq, int retryCount, PROG_STATUS progStatus);
```

and my params to the query are: 60, 2, 1, PROG_STATUS.INPROGRESS

But I am getting this error:

> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Unknown name value [] for enum class [com.myCompany.app.model.RealTimeUpdateLog$PROG_STATUS]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown name value [] for enum class [com.myCompany.app.model.RealTimeUpdateLog$PROG_STATUS]

Can someone help me? Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked the values in the database?

Comment: The values are INPROGRESS, SUCCESS or FAILURE or null.

Comment: `A data base column that you want to map to a Java Enum may not be nullable`